# Setting table name in namespace model

Tags: namespaces, ruby-on-rails-3.2, testunit, legacy-database

I have some namespaced models which I'm trying to override the default rails table name for them because I'm connecting to an existing legacy database.

My models are:

/app/models/licenses.rb

```
  module Licenses
    def self.table_name_prefix
      ''
    end
  end
```

/app/models/licenses/employee.rb

```
class Licenses::Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/licenses_database.yml"))[Rails.env]
  self.table_name = 'EMPLOYEE'
  self.primary_key = 'EMPLOYEE_ID'
end
```

/app/models/licenses/inspection.rb

```
class Licenses::Inspection < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/licenses_database.yml"))[Rails.env]
  self.table_name = 'INSPECTION'
  self.primary_key = 'INSPECTION_ID'
end
```

When I run my tests, errors are generated as the

> PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "licenses_employees" does not
>   exist

Is there something I'm missing to remove the prefix from the namespaced models?

UPDATE: I've tried setting the table name prefix in the Licenses module to 'testing_' instead of '' and I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the issue at hand was that I used the rails generator to create the namespace models for the existing database. The generator had created the fixture files as namespaced fixtures i.e. `/test/fixtures/licenses/employees.yml`. When I tried to run my tests, Rails would try to insert the fixtures into the tables based on the fixture name/path. I just needed to move the fixture files for the existing database and rename them to match the table name that I set in the models i.e. `/test/fixtures/licenses/employee.yml`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! However, when I run my tests, now I am getting errors saying that "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint". Were you able to get around this problem?